# Best Practice IIS Web Sites

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am looking for general information regarding the below scenario.  I am just looking for opinions.  I myself think the first option is better and offers less headaches.

You have an IIS website (www.site.com) that is hit millions of times per day.  You have 5 web servers serving the traffic.  After a while, the worker processes begin to reach their limit.  There are 3 worker processes and one app pool per server.

Option 1: Turn these 5 physical servers into virtual hosts and run 4 VMs from each.  That increases the pool of servers to 20.  Drop worker processes to 2 and have 1 app pool per VM.

Option 2:  Add 5 for IPs for each physical server and 5 instances of the same site on each physical server.  For example, Server 1 will have 5 IPs and 5 IIS app pools and 5 IIS websites called something like this.  Site1, Site2, Site3, Site4, Site5.  Yet all of these go to www.site.com.

I personally think Option 2 is ridiculous.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Both options are nonsense. Why do you ask this question ?

Comment: This is the way that my company wants to move.  If they want more resources I at least think we need to virtualize the web layer to save money at the very least.

Comment: And please tell me why before you just down vote.  Have some balls and at least call me stupid....

Comment: I think this question better fits on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good you ask. Both options seem to go in the wrong way.

Option 1 : Turn a physical server into a host and set up 4 virtual machines on it. Each VM will get a quarter of the memory, processor cores and processor time. The host also uses some amount of resources itself. This means that you end up with less power after this change.

Option 2 : You're right, it is ridiculous. It will not improve anything, just add useless complexity.

If your management has such absurde ideas like you discribe, you should really hire a consultant. At least you could get some realistic scenarios to choose.

Is there something that requires the web server to run on premises ? I'd recommend to move to a managed server with a hosting company. They would take care of system administration. This will take a burden off your system administrator ( that doesn't seem to be very competent ).

Comment: Thank you so much for the honest response.  The only reason the web layer is on premise is because no one wants to pay for hosting.  What would you recommend with the given scope?  Increase throughput with no extra resources.

Comment: Oh and one thing to add.  The physical servers have 96 GB of RAM and 32 cores.  Obviously these are quite large for a single web server.

Comment: I don't have experience neither with IIS (we use Apache) nor with such immense hardware (our servers just very basic compared to yours. So I cannot give a recommendation. Also, our websites just have a few thousands of views, so they do not compare to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your insite on this.  I am still leaning to option 1 because of our massive hardware and the redundancy of a VM environment.  I think I might close this question though as people just read it and think I am stupid.